# Accessors and Mutators C++

Tags: c++, accessor, mutators

I am currently trying to learn C++ and following an instruction. I've researched on mutators and accessors but I need a simple explanation.

```
class Customer
{
public:
    Customer();
    ~Customer();

private:
    string m_name;
    int m_age;

};
```

Right the code above is in a header file. Within the instructions it is asking me to set a public accessors and mutator for both data. How do I do this?

Also it mentions checking the age is not negative in the mutator. I know how to implement the code but I'm just confused on where to place it. Do I place the validation in this header file? or in the .cpp? or in the main method?

I know this sounds all silly and I'm sure simple but I'd like to try and understand this.

Comment: Thought about googling it - eg. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method#C.2B.2B_example

Comment: mutator tag only has 75 questions. =( So sad. None of the questions with mutator tag from this week have been answered at all. Mutator tag is neglect tag.

Comment: function definition goes in the header. implementation (and validation) goes in the cpp.  you could put the validation in the main, but then you'd have to re-implement the validation if you want to reuse the class in other projects.

Comment: You want to start by writing **a member function**.  Research that and you'll be good.

Comment: They're just regular member functions, declared and defined like any other. The fancy names just mean that one modifies a member variable, while another returns its value (or a reference thereto). The validation is part of the mutator's function definition.

Answer (score 7):

*Accessor* - Member function used to retrieve the data of protected members.

*Mutators* - Member function used to edit the data of protected members.

In your case,

```
class Customer
{
public:
    Customer();
    ~Customer();
    string getName(); // Accessor for the m_name variable
    void editName(string in); // Mutator for the m_name variable

private:
    string m_name;
    int m_age;

};
```

Inside your .cpp file:

```
string Customer::getName() {
    return m_name;
}

void Customer::editName(string in) {
    m_name = in;
}
```

Comment: I believe setName is more common name for a mutator than editName.

Comment: +one for the answer, -one for the condescending opening line.